# sort div by attribute in category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

i tryed to sort any divs by using attribute data-name with jquery or
javascript for each room.

html likes as follow:
I want to sort from A-Z only the usernames div. 
How can i do this? 
Many Thanks for help.

```
<div id="room_1">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Blue"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Zoosa"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Any"></div>
</div>

<div id="room_2">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Blue"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Zoosa"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Any"></div>
</div>

<div id="room_3">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Blue"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Zoosa"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Any"></div>
</div>
```

....

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
function SortByName(a, b){
    var aName = a.toLowerCase();
    var bName = b.toLowerCase(); 
    return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}

function sortDiv(target,divs){
    var tempArray = [];

    $(divs).each(function(i,o){
    tempArray.push($(o).data('name'));
});

   tempArray.sort(SortByName);


    $(tempArray).each(function(i,o){
        target.append(target.find('.userlist[data-name='+o+']'));
    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    sortDiv( $('#room_1'),$('#room_1').find('.userlist'));
});
```

Demon :

http://jsfiddle.net/ynhpwvL9/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do,

```
$("#room_1 .userlist").sort(function (first, second) {    
    return $(first).data('name') > $(second).data('name');
}).appendTo($("#room_1"));
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/v774ju34/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I have done the sorting in jsfiddle, please go through the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/jnLLLtt4/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sortData("room_1");
});

function sortData(divId){
var arr = new Array();
    $("#"+divId+" div.userlist").each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).attr('data-name'));
    });
    arr = arr.sort();
var prevdiv='';
    $.each(arr,function(key, val){
        if(prevdiv!=''){
            $cloned = $("#"+divId+" div.userlist[data-name="+val+"]").clone();
        $("#"+divId+" div.userlist[data-name="+val+"]").remove()
            $cloned.insertAfter("#"+divId+" div.userlist[data-name="+prevdiv+"]");
        }else{
            $cloned = $("#"+divId+" div.userlist[data-name="+val+"]").clone();
                $("#"+divId+" div.userlist[data-name="+val+"]").remove();
                $cloned.insertAfter("#"+divId+" div.roomheader");
        }
        prevdiv=val;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get all your items, sort them using `.sort()` function with a custom comparer, and then append them back to the initial container.

```js
$(".room").each(function() { // For every room
  var users = $(this).find(".userlist"); // Take every user in a room
  if (users.length === 0) return;
  
  users.sort(function(a, b) { // Sort them out
    var aText = $(a).data("name");
    var bText = $(b).data("name");
    
    if (aText < bText) return -1;
    if (aText > bText) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  
  users.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().append(this); // Append them back in a new order
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room" id="room_1">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
</div>

<div class="room" id="room_2">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Blu_e">Blu_e</div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Zo-osa">Zo-osa</div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Any">Any</div>
</div>

<div class="room" id="room_3">
  <div class="roomheader"></div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Blue">Blue</div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Zoosa">Zoosa</div>
  <div class="userlist" data-name="Any">Any</div>
</div>
```

Read more about [**`Array.prototype.sort()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function at MDN.
Actually, in this example, it is a proxied by jQuery object, but it is not that important :)

Comment: thank you very much. whats happen if no user in a room? i get undefined at this moment.

Comment: no words! this is absolut perfect. many thanks :) im tryed it since 2 days. many many thanks

Comment: hey. sry again. i get some problems with this solution. if users have chars like _ (unterline) or - . so the sorting stops at this time. do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Marcus That's a strange behaviour. What errors does it show in a console? I have updated my answer and added some `_` and `-` symbols - it still works fine.

Comment: hey, no errors in the console.. the sortfuntion doesn´t works correctly. if users a,b,c,d, all is fine. if there a user like list so: a,b,c,c,c,d, _BUBU_, a,a,b,c etc... it stops the sorting if the function get the user with _

Comment: create a list like ark,berta,cesar,dora,[underline]BUBU[underline], arki,barki,carki,dorki

Comment: really strange but you´re right. ok :/ i have to go to find out the problem why this dont works on my site. many thanks :)

Comment: hey, i was looking at 2 times now. but a can´t find the problem. i tryed now the fiddle with some usernames from my room. but same here. watch https://jsfiddle.net/66pk20s7/1/

Comment: problem found: 

        var aText = $(a).data("name").toLowerCase();
        var bText = $(b).data("name").toLowerCase();

now it works.. thank you